# Using text-align: center and margin: auto to center element in div WITHOUT shrinking background color as well?

Tags: html, css

New to web development, but this was the only way i found to center something without hard coding, but it shrinks the background color align with the centering. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Yes there is a way around that. If you posted some code, we could show you what you need to change.

Comment: And the way around is called flexbox.

Comment: @Highdef thanks, making the containing element display flex worked perfectly ie

grid-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

Comment: @hehexd2222 No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Without any code, it is difficult to say, but maybe try:

```
background-size: 100%;
```

or a quick search showed:

```
background-clip:content-box;
```

Not sure of its relevance.

Comment: If it's difficult to say then it's probably best not to answer/guess and instead request clarification and more details.

Comment: True, but I'm waiting for help on my own issue and was just trying to throw out some options to try while he/she waits.

Comment: That's not really the way things work around here. Kudos for wanting to help, but try and stick the format of the site. If you earn 50 rep you can comment, which is what this answer should have been. Cheers